# How to design a layout for 1080*1920 pixel screens? Which layout folder works for Samsung galaxy S4?

Tags: android, galaxy

I'm creating an application which works for all types of screens, but I'm having problems while creating layouts for the Samsung Galaxy S4 1080*1920 (5 inch screen).

Since 1080*1920 falls under 480dpi(XXHDPI), I have created folder called layout-sw480dp and have placed my file in there.

When I look at it from xml view it looks perfect,  but when I run it and check, the alignment has been changed.

I have created other folders, such as layout-xxhdpi as well,  and tried then but the alignment problem persists.

Are there any specific folders to place files for Samsung Galaxy S4?

I have attached links to show the problem I'm facing.

Thanks in advance

Here is the link for the screenshots

https://www.dropbox.com/s/65pqq65qm2va8jc/xml.gif

https://www.dropbox.com/s/3ewytmrt1jy7xc9/screenshot2.gif

Comment: Check the UI guideline on the android developers' blog: http://android-developers.blogspot.com.br/2011/07/new-tools-for-managing-screen-sizes.html

Comment: Share the layout XML.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to have a layout for your S4, you need to use the `values-sw360dp` folder.

The conversion is like this: `px * 160 / dpi`.
In your case: `1080 * 160 / 480 = 360`.

But anyway, your layout should work on all devices, not only the S4.

Comment: s4 comes under 441 DPI right ?
I have used layout-xhdpi,it worked fine.

Comment: I don't know, how much DPI the S4 has. I just used your value.